# Avoid duplicate labels on river sections and choose placements

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am trying to label rivers's names.
The rivers include multiple  sections. I have many repeats like "fleuve Loire ". 
How to avoid labeling repetition? "Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels" does not seem to be sufficient.

How to place the labels at the "middle" of each river (sum of sections /2)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Under `Placement` select curved. It will reduce the the number of labels and the names will follow the shape of rivers. Another possible way is to activate `Limit number of features smaller than` and select some threshold value in `mm`.

Comment: You could dissolve your layer using the `TOPONYME` field which would give you a single feature for each river.